# ClipChildren with a margin

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have only 1 fragment which covers some part of the screen. In that fragment I have FrameLayout at top and canvas as children of top frameLayout. If I set clipChildren as false and draw lines on canvas then go out of canvas size and are visible from one end of screen to another. If I set clipChidren as true then those lines are not visible out of frameLayout.
What I want is to draw a line which is  visible only for say 10px out of frameLayout and not from end to end. Please note I do not have an option to limit the length of the line on canvas. In short  I want to do clip children but with a negative margin of FrameLayout.

Comment: Any recommendations??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using padding setPadding api on the view. It can be done from xml too if your views are not going to resized in code.